# CSS - background color of table row odd/even

Tags: php, css

I have a table that is dynamically generated by PHP.  I am hoping that I can use CSS to apply a background color based on where the table row is odd/even, i.e. the background color rotates every other row.

Does that make sense?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [nth-of-type()](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype) or [nth-child()](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) selector in CSS3. Supported by all modern Browsers.

For example...

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }

/* Do this… */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }

/* …or this */
tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #ccc; }
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this :

css:

```
.row0{
 background:white;
}
.row1{
 background:black;
}
```

in php while printing rows (trs)

```
<?php

$i = 0;
foreach( ... ){

$i = 1-$i;
$class = "row$i";
?>
<tr class="<?php echo $class ?>">
...
```

Comment: your `$i` is not incremented ever

Comment: @diEcho - `$i = 1-$i;` will toggle $i between 0 and 1

Answer (score 6):

In theory it's as easy as `tr:nth-child(even) { background: #999; }` However, support for nth-child [isn't amazing](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css#css3pseudoclasses) and will only work on the newest browsers

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CrQT5/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      thead, tr:nth-child(even) { background: #aaa; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yuy true but IE and `nth-child` :(

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
$counter = 0;
while(............){
  $counter++;

  $bgcolor = ($counter % 2 === 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';

}
```

Now you can use `bgcolor="<?php echo $bgcolor;?>"` for your `TDs` :)

Note that above will work in all browsers including IE6.

Comment: +1 for the `%2`, but it is better to separate CSS and HTML. Rather then outputting the color itself you should output a class name.

Comment: @nico: Agreed, OP might want to go for classes instead, just posted it quickly :)

Comment: to change background color, we must apply css to `tr` not `td` bcoz if there is cellspacing & cellpadding is given then its looks bad

Answer (score 3):

In CSS define the below class

```
.color0 { #fff; }
.color1 { #ccc; }
```

In PHP Code use the below technique

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    echo "<tr class='color$c'>"; 
    echo "<td>data</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";

    $c=!$c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i guess the best option is to use the internal iterator of foreach :

example :

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($foo as $key => &$bar) : ?>
<tr class="<?php echo ($key + 1) % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">
<td> ... </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is My way, you can try this

```
<style type="text/css">
.even{
 background-color:#333;
}
.odd{
 background-color:#666;
}
</style>

<?php
$i=0;
foreach( ... ){ 
++$i;
?>
<tr class="<?php echo ($i%2) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
 <td>..</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

For have a small php inside your html you can use

```
<?php echo ($striped)?'even':'odd';$striped=!$striped;?>
```

use alternate between even and odd.

Answer (score 0):

just do like this

```
   $codd[0] = 'even';
   $codd[1] = 'odd';
   $codd_i = 1;
   foreach($items as $item){        
   $codd_i = ($codd_i+1)%2;

?>

<tr class="<?php echo $codd[$codd_i] ?>">

</tr>

<?php } >
```