# How to have two background color in a td without spanning it?

Tags: html

Hi Sir/madam i want to have a different background in the top and bottom of td, i.e first half should be in green color and second half in red color...

Comment: have you tried using gradients?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836134/css-background-color-of-table-row-odd-even

Comment: I won't tried it Mr.Mark Dee

Comment: I checked your link Mr.Ophintor but its for changing the background alternatively for odd and even rows

Comment: well, just use an image then http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dyfxo

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

incase you don't like gradients (just for fun). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqdvB

Comment: Thank You Mr.Mark Dee, now i got my output

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Gradients. In your case, the CSS will be:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,255,0) 50%, rgb(255,0,0) 50%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,255,0) 50%, rgb(255,0,0) 50%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,255,0) 50%, rgb(255,0,0) 50%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,255,0) 50%, rgb(255,0,0) 50%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,255,0) 50%, rgb(255,0,0) 50%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.5, rgb(0,255,0)),
    color-stop(0.5, rgb(255,0,0))
);
```

Use this site for generating more: http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Answer (score 1):

To do this directly you could set an image with this feature as background.
Something like

```
style="background-image:url(twocolor.png);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a gradient:

```
td {
    background: #00ff00;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 49%, #ff0000 50%, #ff0000 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00ff00), color-stop(49%,#00ff00), color-stop(50%,#ff0000), color-stop(100%,#ff0000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00ff00 0%,#00ff00 49%,#ff0000 50%,#ff0000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00ff00 0%,#00ff00 49%,#ff0000 50%,#ff0000 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00ff00 0%,#00ff00 49%,#ff0000 50%,#ff0000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00ff00 0%,#00ff00 49%,#ff0000 50%,#ff0000 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ff00', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=0 );
}
```

To edit this gradient use [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#00ff00+0,00ff00+49,ff0000+50,ff0000+100;Gradient).