# SYMFONY 2.8 + Bootstrap, - different colors for odd even rows in tables

Tags: css, twig, html-table

Using twig, how do I add alternating colors to my table rows?

```
 {% if pagination.getTotalItemCount > 0 %}
        <div class="top17 panel panel-default">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
                {% for item in pagination  %}



                    <tr class="tr-hover redirect" data-url="{{ url('item_details', {'id' : item.id}) }}">
                        <td class="hidden-xs item-image"><img src="{{ asset(item.webPath) }}"/></td>
                        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">{{ item.topic }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.price }} SM</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ url('buy_item', { 'id' : item.id }) }}" class="btn btn-success">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                                <span class="hidden-xs">{{  "Buy" | trans }}</span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                            </tr>

                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: any help? If you can't help, just pass away..

Comment: @Sam Dufel - thank you for edit!

Answer (score 0):

This has been already questioned before here.

[CSS - background color of table row odd/even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836134/css-background-color-of-table-row-odd-even)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of posting that as an answer, flag the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @msfontana - it's only CSS, I'm looking the way to do that in TWIG