# How to split an array into groups of 3 and then style every other row differently?

Tags: php, arrays, styling, listitem

If I have an array like this:

```
$food = array('steak', 'chicken', 'vegetables', etc);
```

How can I loop through the array and display each of the items in a list of 3, and also style every other row differently?

Like:

```
Steak chicken vegetables 
Stuff stuff stuff // style this one differently
Blah blah blah
Stuff stuff stuff // style differently
```

I know I can do:

```
foreach (array_chunk($food, 3, true) as $array) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Just not sure how to get the every other row thing in addition to that.

Comment: you want to use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: and for your styling, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836134/css-background-color-of-table-row-odd-even

Comment: Look for the modulo % operator. 'If($i%3===0){dostuff}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `foreach()` loop, add the `key` to the `as key => value`. Then you can use modulo `%` to modify every other row.

```
foreach (array_chunk($food, 3, true) as $key => $array) {
    $oddeven = ($key%2 == 1) ? ' class="even"' : '';
    echo '<ul'.$oddeven.'>';
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

example - https://3v4l.org/LdSgJ

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid writing an inner loop by using `implode()`.  You don't need to assign "even" and "odd" classes if you use the right css declarations.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gg6dl))

```
$food = ['steak', 'chicken', 'vegetables', 'stuff'];
foreach (array_chunk($food, 3) as $batch) {
    echo "<ul><li>" , implode("</li><li>", $batch) , "</li></ul>";
}
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>steak</li>
    <li>chicken</li>
    <li>vegetables</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>stuff</li>
</ul>
```

Once you have the html sorted out, you only need to use `nth-child()` logic in your css.

```css
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: orange;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>steak</li>
 <li>chicken</li>
 <li>vegetables</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>stuff</li>
</ul>
```